# Can I do fragment caching with NGINX fastcgi?

Tags: nginx, cache

I have an NGINX fastcgi cache setup on a site, it works really well. But now I would need to get the user's geographical location from NGINX to PHP, and do some redirecting based on that.

I was thinking if I can always have my `head.php` fresh on every page load. Can I do that with NGINX? I know it's doable with Varnish using ESI (edge side includes).

In NGINX I have something like this:

```
geoip_country /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE $geoip_country_code;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE3 $geoip_country_code3;
fastcgi_param GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME $geoip_country_name;
```

Then I could read those in `head.php` and do a `wp_redirect()` to the right country page.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit how this ties into your WP installation? WP is mostly not very good at fragment caching since core load is relatively heavy and it has poor awareness of HTTP cache responses and such.

Comment: I have WP running on an NGINX server, I use fastcgi cache, user always gets a static html page. I would like to do: `if ($country == 'it' && $lang == 'it') { wp_redirect('/it/' . $localiced_path . '/?lang=it') }` but I don't have access to `$country` or `$lang` since the page is static. I'm thinking that if I exclude the `head.php` from cache, it is always fresh. I'm I approaching this the right way?